# How do I disconnect a projector (SAMSUNG) that I've not connected in the first place??

Tags: display, macos

So my screen is shattered, lights out....I've been connecting to my Samsung tv via minidisplay/hdmi adaptor, and have had no problems until Sierra. Almost immediately after the install, I noticed more display options in the menu bar, one of which reads "connected projector:SAMSUNG", although it's shaded out and I can't select it.  My actual display connection is check marked below it, so I know it's not just telling me what I'm sitting in front of.  What gives?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: What happens if you restart the computer? Note that Samsung TVs call themselves "projectors". That's why you're seeing this "projector" icon

Comment: It's always there.  It's essentially telling me I'm connected to two different displays, the one I'm staring at now, and ????  AirPlay is OFF, and is constantly searching for AppleTV, which I don't have.  I'm at least 120ft away from the nearest samsung device of any kind.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the PRAM? (Turn computer sound up, turn computer off. Press power button and hold down "command", "option", "p", and "r" until you hear the startup noise twice, then release and let computer start up)

Comment: @MrMacTheOneDJ Your comment makes no sense in relation to your question. You state "I've been connecting to my Samsung tv..." but in your comment, "I'm at least 120ft away from the nearest samsung device of any kind." Which is it?